# Nginx (proxy manager) - Custom location redirection issue

Tags: docker, nginx

I have a problem regarding the configuration of Stirling Pdf behind a reverse proxy.

I am using Nginx Proxy Manager in a docker container accessible at `(http)192.168.1.10:81`.

Stirling pdf is accessible at `(http)192.168.1.10:5556`.

I am using these docker on a Synology NAS.

My config:

```
domain name: test.example.com
scheme http
forward ip: a.b.c.d
forward port: 1234
cache, exploits, websocket: everything disable
Publicly accessible
```

(I set up the domain name as `a.b.c.d:1234` just to point test.example.com to nothing. That's also why I add a custom nginx config in Advanced tab.)

SSL: let's encrypt, everything box checked.

Advanced:

```
location / {
  return 404;
}
```

What I've tried in custom location (everything tried in private browser, so the first page of should be the login page):

Custom location:

#### 1.

```
location: /pdf
forward ip: 192.168.1.10
forward port: 5556
custom config: <empty>
```

→ `test.example.com/pdf` → 302 found → redirect to `/login` → not working 404

Here, it should redirect to `.../pdf/login` I think.

#### 2.

```
location: /pdf
forward ip: 192.168.1.10/
forward port: 5556
custom config: <empty>
```

→ `test.example.com/pdf` → redirect to `/login` → not working 404

→ `test.example.com/pdf/` → error page of stirling pdf without css working (e.g. no icons), still not the login page.

#### 3.

```
location: /pdf
forward ip: 192.168.1.10
forward port: 5556
custom config:
location /pdf {
  proxy_pass http://192.168.1.10:5556;
}
```

→ `test.example.com/pdf` → 302 found redirect to `/login` → not working 404

Same thing happen if I put this in custom config:

```
location /pdf {
  proxy_pass http://192.168.1.10:5556/;
  rewrite ^/pdf(/.*)$ $1 break;
}
```

I also tried different rewrite code but none of them work:

```
rewrite ^/pdf/(.*) /$1 break;
rewrite /pdf(/.*|$) /$1  break;
rewrite ^/pdf/(.*)$ /pdf/$1 break;
```

I also tried without the custom nginx config without the return 404;.

If I remove `a.b.c.d:1234` and `location / { return 404;}` and replace it to `192.168.1.10:5556`, it works, but I don't want this. I want to access the website only through `(https)test.example.com/pdf` and `(https)test.example.com/` should be a 404.

I am clearly misunderstanding something. Please can anyone help me with this?

Just to try, I set up `pdf.example.com` with a forward ip to `http://192.168.1.10:5556` and everything works fine without any further config. But that's not what I want.

### Summary

Sometimes it doesn't work, sometimes `(https)test.example.com/pdf` redirects to `https://test.example.com/login` instead of `(https)test.example.com/pdf/login`

What is expected:

`https://test.example.com/pdf` → (redirection) `https://test.example.com/pdf/login` → (success) (redirection) → `https://test.example.com.pdf/`